# EPPlus DataTable Exporting to Excel is Putting my Data into a Popup

Tags: c#, excel, popup, epplus

EPPlus DataTable Exporting to Excel is Putting my Data into a Popup. The popup says Error: OK Contains some data and random characters without grid lines. Has an 'ok' button on the popup that just closes the popup. No errors on build or in console.

```
         public void DownloadExcel(EntityReportModel erModel, string 
          filename) {
        var dataResponse = iEntityViewService.LoadEntityView(new 
          EntityViewInput
        {
            SecurityContext = SessionCache.Instance.SecurityContext,
            EntityViewName = "Ticket",
            Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                {"MinTicketDateTime", "04/26/16"}
        });

        var table = dataResponse.DataSet.Tables[0];
        filename = "NGLTICKETS";
        using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(filename);
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "attachment; filename={0}.xlsx", filename));
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pack.GetAsByteArray());
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add extension to filename.. `String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "attachment; filename={0}.xlsx", filename)`

Comment: @vendettamit thank you but that did not change the result.